# Access SimpleXMLElement child elements as an array

Tags: php, simplexml

How can I Access the SimpleXMLElement childs as an array?

```
SimpleXMLElement(9) {
 name => "John" (11)
 phone => array(2) [
    0 => "556 221 000" (19)
    1 => "312 555 110" (19)
 ]
}
```

According to this article http://www.sitepoint.com/parsing-xml-with-simplexml/ I should easily access it via

```
$sxElement->phone[0];
```

But then dump returns just:

```
SimpleXMLElement(0)
```

I need to access this in a for cycle. Thanks.

Edit (XML example):

```
<company>
  <phonebook>
    <name>John</name>
    <phone>556 221 000</phone>
    <phone>312 555 110</phone>
  </phonebook>
</company>
```

I need to go thru my foreach on another object and attach the correct phone according to iterator value.

Comment: have you tried `foreach($sxElement->phone as $value){}`? You might need `foreach($sxElement->phone as (string)$value){}`

Comment: Can you post the XML please?

Comment: XML attached in the edit

Comment: Do not rely on `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc to inspect SimpleXML objects. I've written [some alternative debugging functions](https://github.com/imsop/simplexml_debug) which might give you clearer ideas.

Comment: that sitepoint article is very good and onlyone that helped me solved mine issue of accessing nested namespace `current($xml->attributes(current($xml->getNamespaces(true)))->noNamespaceSchemaLocation)`, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
$sxElement->phone[0]->__toString();
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Or, more "naturally", cast to string: `(string)$sxElement->phone[0]`

Comment: Note that if you had used `echo` rather than `var_dump`, it would have implicitly performed this cast to string. It is only `var_dump` which misled you to thinking the element was empty.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast the data to an array so try this out (it worked for me).

```
$el = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<company>
      <phonebook>
        <name>John</name>
        <phone>556 221 000</phone>
        <phone>312 555 110</phone>
      </phonebook>
    </company>'
);

$array = (array) $el->phonebook->phone;
```

The output of this is an `array` ready for manipulation.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 556 221 000
    [1] => 312 555 110
)
```

Another method that will get the key as well.

```
foreach($sxElement->phone as $i => $value) {
    echo "{$i} : {$value}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Although this cannot be accessed by the outer loop.

Comment: I need to acces to the array key according to the iterator of some outer foreach. The ->children() method returns SimpleXMLElement(0) too.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have found when working with simpleXML when I want to work with arrays is to pass the whole thing into and out of json, using the "true" parameter in `json_decode()`. Then I have an associative array that is more what I'm accustomed to working with.

Comment: Generally speaking, all the things you can do after this you can do before as well, if you understand how SimpleXML works, and resist the temptation to look at `print_r` or `var_dump` output.